# How to enable gzip for nginx within a Dokku instance?

Tags: node.js, nginx, dokku

I have a node.js app deployed using [Dokku](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku%7Ev0.5.0/) *(version 0.11.6)* on a [DigitalOcean droplet](https://www.digitalocean.com/products/droplets/). I need to enable gzip within nginx but I'm finding the documentation confusing. It states:

> Dokku uses a templating library by the name of [sigil](https://github.com/gliderlabs/sigil) to generate nginx >configuration for each app. You may also provide a custom template for >your application as follows:
>
> Copy the following example template to a file named `nginx.conf.sigil` and >either:
>
> - If using a buildpack application, you must check it into the root of your app repo.
> - `ADD` it to your dockerfile `WORKDIR`
> - if your dockerfile has no `WORKDIR`, `ADD` it to the `/app` folder

I am using Dokku with default setup *(as is)* and have never added a buildpack or dockerfile, so these instructions are not making much sense to me. What I would like to know is:

- Is it possible to create a partial Nginx config file that I can include in the root of my source repository that gets applied each time the app is deployed?
- If not, how do I modify the nginx configuration that would ensure it persists between deployments?
- If the config has to be done externally, how would you include some reference to that in the project for future reference?

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Peter Nikolow](https://twitter.com/PeterNikolow) via Twitter and [Alex Ellis](https://twitter.com/alexellisuk) via a Zoom call, the solution is to modify the main nginx config file for the entire server as it eliminates the need to enable gzip for each site.

The steps are:

1. shh as root into your droplet
2. run `nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` to edit the root nginx config file
3. within the `http` block, add the following:

```
gzip on;
gzip_min_length 1000;
gzip_buffers 4 32k;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
```

4. comment out other gzip config by placing a `#` in front of them
5. press `cmd+x` to exit editing followed by `Y` to save the changes
6. run `nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` to test the new config
7. run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
8. and `sudo systemctl restart nginx` to restart nginx

Comment: As of [Dokku v0.3.22](https://github.com/dokku/dokku/releases/tag/v0.3.22), gzip is [enabled by default](https://github.com/dokku/dokku/pull/1277/files) at the included server-level nginx.conf. Since then, the nginx support has morphed a bit, but gzip should already be included. By way of example, here are the settings at [v0.11.6](https://github.com/dokku/dokku/blob/v0.11.6/plugins/nginx-vhosts/templates/nginx.conf.sigil#L19).

Comment: I am now running `dokku version 0.18.3` on a fresh Digital Ocean droplet and still running into this problem.

Comment: If you could join us on Slack to discuss this, we can figure out exactly what you're trying to do and why it isn't working out of the box.

Comment: If you're using Cloudflare, check out this 'Transform Rule' solution:https://community.cloudflare.com/t/csv-compression/357981